# what's the difference among "almost," "nearly", and "about" when we talk about approximate numbers?

Tags: difference, usage

What's the difference among these words when we talk about approximate numbers? If I say "almost 3,000 people", "nearly 3,000 people", or "about 3,000 people", can they refer to a number that is just more than 3,000?

Comment: did you check a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only "about 3000 people" can refer to more than 3000. "Almost" and "nearly" both mean *close to but not yet* reaching the number specified. Note that they can be used going down instead of up, depending on the context—but they still mean "not reaching or going beyond the specified number."

I would say that "almost 3000" is not as close to 3000 as "nearly 3000," but that distinction is my personal feeling, not set in stone.